# Combining multiple models trained in different parts of the dataset in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

In PyTorch, is it theoretically possible to 'merge' multiple models together into one model - effectively combining all the data learnt so far? The models are exactly identical, however, are trained with different parts of the training data.

If so, would it be possible to split a dataset into equal parts and distribute training between many computers in a similar manner to folding@home? Would the new model be as good as if it was not distributed?

[image: Diagram detailing this]

Comment: are you building the same model for each part of the dataset?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal exact same model structure, different training data

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are asking for is a distributed implementation of a tensorflow/pytorch model. Similar to distributed databases, chunks of data can be used on separate clusters to train a single model in parallel on each cluster. The resultant model will be trained on all the separate chunks of data on different clusters, as though it has been trained on the complete data together.

While there are multiple tools that do the same, the one I can recommend is Analytics Zoo.

[image]

> A unified Data Analytics and AI platform for distributed TensorFlow, Keras and PyTorch on Apache Spark/Flink & Ray. You can easily apply AI models (e.g., TensorFlow, Keras, PyTorch, BigDL, OpenVINO, etc.) to distributed big data.

More details [here](https://analytics-zoo.github.io/master/).

Comment: Could this be distributed out among many computers in different parts of the world?

Comment: correct. that's the point of a distributed system. Hope that answers your question. Do mark the answer if it did.

Comment: you can create clusters locally as well, for testing purposes, but the general intention is to distribute the data and model training over multiple physically separate servers.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you but do you have any links that could help teach me how to setup a server? I can't seem to find much documentation

Comment: you can find a ton of material on youtube. just search "distributed ai pytorch"

Comment: Here is a link that can get you started on the concept. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQfK_ViGzH0

Comment: Check this as well https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dist_overview.html